# Magento 2.4.5 - {{layout handle="layout" order=$order area="frontend"}}

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.5

I'm trying to get order in my custom template.

```
{{layout handle="layout" order=$order area="frontend"}}
```

And $block->getOrder() method don't work in my template..
It worked in version 2.4.3
How do I translate this into the new 2.4.5 requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migration of email templates is described here in detail
https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/templates/email-migration/